# Context based (parameterised) Queries in Sparx EA

Tags: sql, architecture, enterprise-architect

The Sparx Enterprise Architect Searches are great, however I would like to search for all requirements linked to a specific object (Activity) which I have included on a specific diagram.  On that Diagram, I have added a model view (which can display a SQL query result)

My question is - Is there any way to obtain some sort of contextual perspective to use in the query? - essentially, I would like to know the diagram guid which the ModelView is being run by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't use Model Views, but AFAIK there's nothing extending SQL in that direction. You might want to send a feature request. But don't hold your breath.

On the other hand, if you hard code the GUID of a query, it will work for individual diagrams only. That calls for maintenance issues. Rather, you could stereotype diagrams and use that information in your query.